# SQLException Parameter #7 has not been set

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, authentication

so i am trying to use our login procedure the problem is it that it has three different ways of communicating information back: an `out` parameter, a `return value` and a `result` and i am not sure how to work with that as 
i getting a

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #7 has not been set

what is my 7th param and how exactly should i decalre it? to make this functional

```
protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
    if (userid.trim().equals("") || password.trim().equals("")) z = getString(R.string.wrong_user);
    else {
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = getString(R.string.connection_error);
            } else {
               String query = "{?=call [system].[usp_validateUserLogin](?,?,?,?,?)}";
                    CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(query);
                    cs.registerOutParameter(1,Types.INTEGER);
                    cs.setString(2, userid);
                    cs.setString(3, password);
                    cs.setInt(4, 72);
                    cs.setNull(5, Types.BIT);
                    cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
                    boolean firstResultIsResultSet = cs.execute();
                    if (firstResultIsResultSet) {
                        ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
                        // process result set
                    }
                }
                //if (rs.next()) {
                 //   z = getString(R.string.login_succes);
                 //   isSuccess = true;
               // } else {
               //     z = getString(R.string.Invalid_Credentials);
               //     isSuccess = false;
               // }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            z = getString(R.string.Exceptions);
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

i have the SP as folowing

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [system].[usp_validateUserLogin]
    @p_Login                NVARCHAR ( 50 ),
    @p_Password             NVARCHAR ( 32 ),
    @p_CompanyID            INT,
    @p_OutDetails           BIT = 1,
    @p_AuthenticationTicket VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @errNo    INT,
              @recCount INT,
              @res      INT

      SELECT u.*
      INTO   #TMPLOGIN
      FROM   SYSTEM.[user] AS u WITH ( NOLOCK )
      WHERE  ( u.login = @p_Login )
             AND ( u.company_id = @p_CompanyID )
             AND ( PWDCOMPARE (@p_Password, u.passwd) = 1 )
             AND ( u.status = 0 ) --Active
      SELECT @errNo = @@ERROR,
             @recCount = @@ROWCOUNT

      IF ( @errNo <> 0 )
        BEGIN
            RETURN 1010
        END

      IF ( @recCount = 1 )
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @userID INT

            SELECT @userID = id
            FROM   #TMPLOGIN

            EXEC @res = SYSTEM.USP_RENEWAUTHENTICATIONTICKET
              @p_DoerTicket = '',
              @p_AuthenticationTicket = @p_AuthenticationTicket OUTPUT,
              @p_UserID = @userID,
              @p_CompanyID = @p_CompanyID

            IF ( @res <> 0 )
              RETURN @res
        END

      --SET @p_AuthenticationTicket = 'TESTAUTHENTICATIONTICKET0123456789'
      IF ( @p_OutDetails = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM   #TMPLOGIN
        END

      RETURN 0
  END
```

[image]

what i had been trying so far

1. `String query = "{call [system].[usp_validateUserLogin](?,?,?,?,?)}";`

gaved me

> The executeQuery method must return a result

2. `cs.setNull(7, Types.NULL);`

then i gets a

> java.sql.SQLException: Procedure or function usp_validateUserLogin has too many arguments specified.

3. `cs.setInt(5, 1);`
   still the same
4. `ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();`

instead of

```
boolean firstResultIsResultSet = cs.execute();
```

Comment: You really should be salting and hashing your passwords instead of plain text like this. Also, be extremely careful using NOLOCK here. That hint brings a lot of baggage that most people don't fully understand. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: iknow but i am not the one that had programmed the DB. iam just trying to make a third party program. so i am not allowed to change anything in the SP as that would affect the main program

Comment: A while back, I came across something similar at [another site](https://coderanch.com/t/297496/databases/calling-stored-procedure) where they seemed to have the same issue. Their `CallableStatement` only worked if they took out the braces `{  }` from the query. Don't know if it will help, but it (probably) won't hurt to try.

Comment: that didn't worked

Comment: You call `cs.Execute` twice. Not the cause of the error, in all likelihood, but probably not what's intended either. On what line, exactly, are you getting the error?

Comment: oh i see i removed the `cs.execute` and the Parameter #7 has not been set. still occur on 
`boolean firstResultIsResultSet = cs.execute();`

Comment: It's not something daft like zero based is it? Start at 0 rather than 1?

Comment: the outdetails in parameter 5? that one i am not also 100% sure about and if i had it declared right

Comment: Try not setting it at all. Or even better just for a test try actually setting it. Normally when you give it a default value you don't need to set anything so maybe by setting it  to null it's causing an issue like you think.

Comment: i tryed without it and then it gaved me the error on param 5 and then i tryed with cs.setint 1 and it gaved me the error again on param 7

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0802tiwary/) there's a section that shows similar code to what you're doing. It has {? = call c_out_proc(?,?)} and it only sets parameters for the two in (?,?) not the first ? = call. So maybe try and only set for the parameters between the brackets at the end.

Comment: i had used it before wthout ?= but there i got the issue that The executeQuery method must return a result and to solve that issue i was needed to use ?= to get all the return values

Comment: No, set it within the query String but don't initialise it as a parameter in the cs. Start with userId as parameter 1 and finish with the registerOutParameter as parameter 5. If that makes sense. That's what the example does.

Comment: I not familiar with java programming..but can you first dump/log the query string before execute and test that in sql server..?

Comment: @jinx then is just Parameter #6 has not been set instead

Comment: In many examples I've seen executeUpdate() is used to call stored procedures. Did you try this?

Comment: execute update is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that cs.setNull(5, Types.BIT) won't behave as you expect (setting default value equals 1 for @p_OutDetails) You must do cs.setBoolean(5, true) or use named parameters {?=call [system].usp_validateUserLogin}

Other than that, your code is fine, so the problem must be somewhere else. Are you actually connecting to the database that you think? Are you sure that the procedure definition in the database is the same that you posted?

Comment: embarrassing i figured out that i had a ? to much in my (?,?,?,?,?) but then i fixed that i couldn't still log in so i tryed cs.setboolean(5,true) instead and then it worked perfectly